# Graph ops missing from the python registry Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use universal sentence encoder multilingual module. I am using tensorflow 1.14 version. After referring to other questions on stackoverflow, one possible reason was using old version of tensorflow, which is not the case here.

Update : Added python packages version

```
###  Tensorflow version : 1.14.0
###  sentencepiece: 0.1.82
###  tf-sentencepiece: 0.1.82.1

use_large_module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3" #@param ["https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2", "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3"]
use_lite_module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-lite/2"
use_multilingual_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/1'  #@param ['https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/1', 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/1', 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-xling-many/1']

# embed = hub.Module(use_lite_module_url)
# embed = hub.Module(use_large_module_url)
embed = hub.Module(use_multilingual_url)
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-22dba73760e9> in <module>()
      5 # embed = hub.Module(use_lite_module_url)
      6 # embed = hub.Module(use_large_module_url)
----> 7 embed = hub.Module(use_multilingual_url)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/module.py in __init__(self, spec, trainable, name, tags)
    168           name=self._name,
    169           trainable=self._trainable,
--> 170           tags=self._tags)
    171       # pylint: enable=protected-access
    172 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py in _create_impl(self, name, trainable, tags)
    338         trainable=trainable,
    339         checkpoint_path=self._checkpoint_variables_path,
--> 340         name=name)
    341 
    342   def _export(self, path, variables_saver):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py in __init__(self, spec, meta_graph, trainable, checkpoint_path, name)
    380 
    381     register_ops_if_needed({
--> 382         op.name for op in self._meta_graph.meta_info_def.stripped_op_list.op})
    383 
    384     if _is_tpu_graph_function():

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py in register_ops_if_needed(graph_ops)
    820         "Graph ops missing from the python registry (%s) are also absent from "
    821         "the c++ registry."
--> 822         % missing_ops.difference(set(cpp_registry_ops.keys())))
    823 
    824 

NotFoundError: Graph ops missing from the python registry ({'SentencepieceEncodeSparse'}) are also absent from the c++ registry.
```

Comment: Do you have `sentencepiece` and `tf_sentencepiece` installed and imported?

Comment: @James I have updated the description

Comment: Same error here. Googled a while but didn't find any solution: "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Graph ops missing from the python registry ({'SentencepieceEncodeSparse'}) are also absent from the c++ registry."

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here. Here's how I fixed it:

```
pip install tf_sentencepiece
```

and then you have to load it inside code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tf_sentencepiece # <- ADD THIS

embed = hub.Module(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error msg it's not evident. To resolve this error do the below

```
pip install tensorflow_text
```

and in your python script import

```
import tensorflow_text as tf_txt
```

This should resolve the above error.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows I believe there is no solution available at this moment, but if you are in Linux/Ubuntu try the following:

```
TFHUB_CACHE_DIR=/data/models/tf-hub
```

(data/models is your local path, change it as you please)

And create one environment variable, and then

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

To reflect changes. Good luck